# CMsg identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm starting to learn Visual C++ and I wanted to make an application where I take strings from a String Table resource and display them in different controls.
I've been using this method of getting the strings, which works just fine,

```
CString mystr;
mystr.LoadString(IDS_MYSTR);
GetDlgItem(IDC_MYSTATIC) -> SetWindowTextW(mystr);
```

Which works just fine, but I'm creating variables that I'm only using once and I would like a one liner solution, so I found a lot of people were using this:

```
GetDlgItem(IDC_MYSTATIC) -> SetWindowTextW(CMsg(IDS_MYSTRING));
```

Which looks like a much better and efficient solution (not sure, noob here), but for me it doesn't work. I'm getting this error when I try to run my application:

```
error C3861: 'CMsg': identifier not found
```

I wasn't able to find that much information about CMsg on the web, but I saw it in quite a few questions here and on other websites. I'm guessing there's a library or header I need to import, but I'm not sure what should I import.

I don't think the whole code is necesary for this, but I'm wondering if it's something to do with the fact that I'm making the app for a Windows Mobile Pocket PC. It should be a standard method, not platform related. I also don't think this question is a duplicate, as I was unable to find here a question that was related to this specific function/method/structure, whatever it is.

Comment: Can you double check you're using [the right header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/cmsg-cmsg) (which appears to be Msgthrd.h)?

Comment: I think the one-liner you've found on the web is using the custom `CMsg` (and `CFMsg`) classes written by Serge Wautier, see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10542/Easily-Load-and-Format-Strings-from-the-String-Tab

Comment: @heapunderrun That's what I ended up finding, but at first I thought it was a normal C++ class. Beginner here.

Comment: Is this MFC? There is a tag for that.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit more lurking, it seems like `CMsg` is a custom structure made by someone. I found an example that contained 2 classes, `CMsg` and `CFMsg`.

I found the code from this CodeProject page: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10542/Easily-Load-and-Format-Strings-from-the-String-Tab?PageFlow=Fluid and it's what I needed.

I ended up taking it, stripping it down to the bare bones that were perfect for me and putting it into a single header file, or just pasting it into my main code file:

```
class CMsg : public CString {
    public : CMsg(int nID);
}; CMsg::CMsg(int nID) {
    if (!LoadString(nID)) {}
}
```

Comment: Or you could use the builtin constructor directly as `CString(MAKEINTRESOURCE(nID))` as mentioned on the linked page as well.

Comment: For me it did not work. The stripped down code is working well, despite me not knowing how in the wou

Comment: For me it did not work. I prefer using the stripped down version of the code from the linked page, which I don't understand how it could work. I'm not assigning or returning any value, but that's a class, at which I am still a beginner in C++.

Comment: There is an example of how it works on the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#cstringt), except they use an explicit cast `(LPCSTR)ID_FILE_NEW` instead of the macro `MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_FILE_NEW)` which does the same thing.